# relevance / most recent selection lost after entering new keyword

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The tabs for relevance / most recent selection is lost once I enter a new keyword.

Example:

I search for test engineer under most recent I can see some jobs.
I then change the keyword from Test Engineer to QA Engineer and click search, the system automatically selects the **relevance** tab for me instead of **most recent**.

There seems to be a session or cookie issue that doesn't seem to stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix pushed to production, thanks for the report!